# HM-11 ble authentication

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using HM-11 ble with arduino .When  put the device in authentication mode(for connectivity ask password) ,its asking password and get connected to android device which is lower than lollipop version.If the version is higher then it's getting connected without password or not getting connected at all(so not ask for password and error message has come pass is not matching.

Answer (score 0):

This is device specific issue you can download sample from [its site](http://www.jnhuamao.cn/) or you need to mail at webmaster@jnhuamao.cn for your [problem](http://www.jnhuamao.cn/download_rom_en.asp?id=#)